# Can exposing firebase auth.uid in you document post a security issue

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I expose my userId in the user documents to make it easier for later use.
Will this create any issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Exposing the user UID does not or will not create any threat to your database until and unless you have your firebase rules properly setup.

Read more about [Firebase Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules).

Comment: This is not entirely true.  An insecure system could still reveal something about a user given a UID, even if the UID itself doesn't contain any data.